# Exception in Try Catch is NOTHING

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch

Really don't know why this and other similar pieces of code are not working in my MVC3 application.

```
  Try
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim b As Integer = 15 / x
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("aaa" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

simply ex is ever nothing. i tried debugging, the debugger enter the catch clause, the VS popup show me the correct exception values... but hovering ex with mouse show it is nothing.
the debug immediate window show the correct message "aaaOverflow arythmetic operation...."

really i'm going crazy!

Comment: Where have you set the breakpoint? If it's on `Catch ex As Exception`, ex is nothing, if it's set on `Debug.WriteLine("aaa" & ex.Message)`, ex cannot be nothing.

Comment: in the debugger, ex is nothing... so ex.message is nothing of course, i checked it.
wherever i set the breakpoint ex is ever nothing. i tried to set it on the TRY statement, then i gor forward 1 step a time with the debugger.... same result. ex is nothing. it seems to be a VS2010 SP1 bug. before the update all was working OK...

Answer (score 1):

There is an object called Err. Err.Description contains the message error. I had the same problem and Err saved